# MVC model binding encrypted value and routing to different parameter type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, encryption, routes

I have an `EncryptedModelBinder` class that I created to be able to encrypt certain values on web pages so that they aren't easily changed by malicious users.

This lets me mark certain model properties as `[Encrypted]`, and when the model binder is binding them it will decrypt them and insert the value.

Example:

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    [Encrypted]
    public int AcctID { get; set; }

    public string SomeValue { get; set; }
}
```

The `AcctID` is then encrypted on the client side and is automatically decrypted in my controller method:

```
public ActionResult EncryptedFormInfo(TestViewModel vm)
{
    //vm.AcctID has the correct value here.
    return View(MVC.Test.Views.Index, vm);
}
```

**My Question is:** how can I make this binding work without an explicit view model?

I have a controller method that just has one parameter that I want to bind:

```
public virtual async Task<ActionResult> _AccountPopover([Encrypted]int acctID)
```

However, the type of that parameter is `int`, and the encrypted value is `string`, which causes the error:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'acctID' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32'...

when given the url with `?acctID=LJsH6ImlIAqQgVsvO%2BHwHA%3D%3D` (an encrypted value of the ID)

I tried to add the route `[Route("Account/_AccountPopover/{acctID}")]` without specifying `:int` on the the parameter to see if that would set up a route for a string, but that didn't work. How can I set a route that will work in this case?

For reference, below is the important part of the `EncryptedModelBinder`:

```
protected override void BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor)
{
    var bindParent = true;
    if (propertyDescriptor.Attributes.Cast<object>().Any(a => a.GetType() == typeof(EncryptedAttribute)))
    {
        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(propertyDescriptor.Name);

        if (value == null)
            throw new ArgumentException($"Unable to get value for encrypted property {propertyDescriptor.Name}");

        var valueDecrypted = Decrypt(value.AttemptedValue); //throw an error if it parsed badly.
        var asType = Convert.ChangeType(valueDecrypted, propertyDescriptor.PropertyType);
        SetProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor, asType);
        bindParent = false;

    }

    if (bindParent) //no [Encrypted] property was properly matched
        base.BindProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor);

}
```

Comment: Hi, try to use the route: [Route("Account/_AccountPopover/{acctID}")] but the parameter type string instead int

Comment: @JulitoAvellaneda the thing is, i don't want to have to manually do an `int.Parse()`, I want the Model Binder to take care of all that stuff

Comment: Not sure how you think encrypting values will protect against malicious users - it more likely to encourage it. If you need the value to be rendered in the view because it must be posted back, then in the controller, create a hash of it and render a hidden input with the hash (say AcctIDHash`). In the POST method, hash the posted `AcctID` value again and compare it with the posted `AcctIDHash` value and if they are the same, the `AcctID` value has not been tampered with.

Comment: @StephenMuecke this will not be the only line of defense- when someone requests info on an AcctID it will always check to make sure that they should have access to it. I was thinking that seeing `?acctID=aCgD3jF5` would be less inviting than seeing `acctID=123`. Obviously we will want to have server-side validation, but my reasoning was that having an extra layer couldn't hurt, and if there is some place where we forget to validate server-side, this could help protect it in a more automatic way.

Comment: Hi, Have you got a solution for this question? :D

Comment: Sorry it's been a long time... I think I recall solving this problem somehow but I have since changed companies and don't have access to the code to check. Sorry @PhanĐứcBình !

Comment: No worries, thanks for replying.